# Printing Values Within a Function

Tags: functions, printing

Below is a function to calculate the overlap between two gaussian functions.

```
Ov[alpha_, beta_, RA_, RB_, LA_, LB_] := Module[{EAB, Overlap},
  Do[
    (* Initial Conditions *)

    s[i_, 0, 0] := 1
       s[i_, 1, 0] := -(RA[[i]] - ((alpha*RA[[i]] + beta*RB[[i]])/(alpha + beta)))

          (* Recurrence Index *)


          s[i_, a_, 0] := -(RA[[
               i]] - (alpha*RA[[i]] + beta*RB[[i]])/(alpha + beta))*
           s[i, a - 1, 0] + ((a - 1)/(2*(alpha + beta)))*
           s[i, a - 2, 0];

        (* Transfer Equation *)

        s[i_, a_, b_] := 
         s[i, a + 1, b - 1] + (RA[[i]] - RB[[i]])*s[i, a, b - 1]

        , {i, 1, 3}];

    EAB = Exp[-(alpha*beta/(alpha + beta))*(RA - RB).(RA - RB)];

    Overlap = EAB*(Pi/(alpha + beta))^(3/2)*s[1, LA[[1]], LB[[1]]]*
      s[2, LA[[2]], LB[[2]]]*
      s[3, LA[[3]], LB[[3]]]
    ];
```

How do I print/debug different values (such as s[1,1,2] etc.) within this function in mathematica notebook? The function works for me in the notebook.

Comment: Hello @Goku , I believe there are some semi-colons missing among the s[] definitions, and I believe the Do loop is superfluous. Is my understanding correct? Also, the last expression of a Block is the returned value

Comment: Yeah, I removed those since I read elsewhere that by removing semicolons, the value of that variable will be printed. I am a complete newbie to mathematica and trying to convert this code to a C equivalent. Hence, I am looking to debug it.

Comment: Note that `Echo` is extremely useful for debugging, as it both returns and prints the value it’s given, so you can just slip it into code, e.g. `f[x_] := Echo[x] + 2` works like `x + 2`, but prints `x` when it encounters it. You can also give tags and a “processing” function as further arguments; check out the documentation.

Comment: (wait...this is from October 2019...why did this show up as I was scrolling? 0_0)

Comment: @thorimur It's happened again.  Community Bot kicks it to top of the active list b/c answers but none upvoted, trying to get someone either to give a better answer or review the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following:

```
Ov[alpha_, beta_, RA_, RB_, LA_, LB_] := Module[{EAB, s, ss},
   (*Initial Conditions*)
   s[i_, 0, 0] := 1;
   s[i_, 1, 0] :=
     -(RA[[i]] - ((alpha*RA[[i]] + beta*RB[[i]])/(alpha + 
           beta)));
   (*Recurrence Index*)
   s[i_, a_, 0] :=
     -(RA[[i]] - (alpha*RA[[i]] + beta*RB[[i]])/(alpha + beta))*
      s[i, a - 1, 0] + ((a - 1)/(2*(alpha + beta)))*s[i, a - 2, 0];
   (*Transfer Equation*)
   s[i_, a_, b_] := 
    s[i, a + 1, b - 1] + (RA[[i]] - RB[[i]])*s[i, a, b - 1];
   (*debugging function*)
   ss[i_, a_, b_] := 
    With[{v = s[i, a, b]}, 
     Print[StringTemplate["s[``,``,``]=``"][i, a, b, v]]; v];
   (*EAB*)
   EAB = Exp[-(alpha*beta/(alpha + beta))*(RA - RB).(RA - RB)];
   Print[StringTemplate["EAB=``"][EAB]];
   (*return Overlap*)
   EAB*(Pi/(alpha + beta))^(3/2)*ss[1, LA[[1]], LB[[1]]]*
    ss[2, LA[[2]], LB[[2]]]*ss[3, LA[[3]], LB[[3]]]
  ]
```

This is the best I can help without knowledge of some typical values for alpha, beta, RA, RB, LA, LB.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have taken the code from here: https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2012/02/evaluation-of-gaussian-molecular-integrals/

Comment: The esteemed authors' code leaves me confused with their use of the Do loop, we may have reached the limit of my ability to help, but I hope the general technique involving Print is clear, don't hesitate to ask for more help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If I need to print values of variables like 'EAB' etc. in the code, do I adapt the same procedure?

Comment: see new edit, @Goku